# c# Form Minimize/Maximize Buttons gone?

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize, maximize-window

On one of my forms the Minimize/Maximize Buttons are gone.
The `ControllBox` is set to `true` as is the `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox`.

Is there some other setting I have missed?

Comment: What is four FormBorderStyle value?

Comment: check your window style

Comment: Are they not displayed or are they inactive, i.e. visible, but cannot be interacted with?

Comment: it was the `FormBorderStyle` it was set to `SizableToolWindow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `FormBorderStyle` on that form,

`FixedToolWindow` and `SizableToolWindow` and `None` doesn't have those controls at all.

Answer (score 2):

Coming late to the game, I still would like to share my answer as I spent a good couple of hours searching for a fix. My form had all the properties set as they should, but still the minimize/maximize buttons wouldn't show.

The culprit was overriding the `CreateParams` method from my form, e.g.

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams Params = base.CreateParams;
            Params.ExStyle |= 0x80;
            return Params;
        }
    }
```

My original intention of overriding this method was to hide my app from the task switcher (alt-tab). I didn't think of this as the reason for not showing the buttons mentioned above, alas, it was.

For further reference, [here is the documentation of the flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles).

Answer (score 0):

In my project, the `FormBorderStyle` was already set to `FixedSingle`. So, I was not sure why the `MinimizeBox`/ `MaximizeBox` were still not visible. Then, somehow, I managed to find an alternative solution for this.

---

Inside of your C# project, simply press: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F` buttons, then search for the `MinimizeBox`/ `MaximizeBox` variables.

I was surprised to find its value set to `False` at first. So, to fix, I simply changed the value from `False` -> `True` then, problem solved.

---

In my case, since it is an open source project, the author has changed its value. So, I just need to find those variables using the `Find in Files` function by Microsoft Visual Studio. It can also be found in the Microsoft Visual Studio's menu bar: `Edit` -> `Find and Replace` -> `Find in Files`.
[image]

Hopefully useful for all of you as well!